# How to apply regex to a column in pandas to find a value and then apply a function to this?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am trying to read large dataset and replace some strings if the value matches a regex.

I found the string using this:

```
result = ds['pagePath'].str.extract( \ 
                        '^\/([^\?]*)\?[^\?]*Code=[^\?]*Reference').str.strip()
```

It looks like it is working and extracts the text of the matching rows, but now I need to format ONLY to this value:

```
 result = '/NewUrl' + result_matching_column + '/somethingelse'
```

What's the best way to do so?

Comment: Naively, would this not work: `ds['pagePath'] = r'/NewUrl' + ds['pagePath'].str.extract( \ 
                        '^\/([^\?]*)\?[^\?]*Code=[^\?]*Reference').str.strip() + r'/somethingelse'` ?

Comment: @jp_data_analysis It could, but, it would  apply to all the values in the column. I only need to apply to the values that match the regex

Comment: Can you provide an example with expected output? An efficient solution can be provided to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use lambda and a function

```
 df['pagePath'].apply(lambda x: regex_lev(x))
```

This is the function:

```
def regex_lev(x):
    url = x
    url = url.replace('/?ReturnUrl', '/xReturnUrl')
    regex =r"^\/([^\?]*)\?[^\?]*communityCode=[^\?]*paymentReference"
    if re.search(regex, url):

        match =  re.search(regex, url)
        result= '/' + match.group(1) + '/payment-complete'
        result = result.replace('//','/')
        result = result.replace('/xReturnUrl', '/?ReturnUrl')
        print("Full match: %s" % (result))

        return result

    else:
        print("NO match: %s" % (x))
        return  x
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work, though inefficient:

```
import numpy as np

ds['extraction'] = ds['pagePath'].str.extract('^\/([^\?]*)\?[^\?]*Code=[^\?]*Reference').str.strip()
ds['pagePath'] = np.where(pd.notnull(ds['extraction']),
                          r'/NewUrl' + ds['extraction'] + r'/somethingelse',
                          ds['pagePath'])
ds = ds.drop('extraction', 1)
```